# Fetch particular data from duplicated record in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I just wanted to know is there a possibility to get specific columns from duplicated row in PHP-MySQL connection and use them to the existing data in JSON?

```
/...db connection etc.

        if ($statement->execute())
        {
             $response["lecturer"] = array();

             while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
                $lecturer = array();
                $lecturer["id"] = $row["lecturerid"];
                $lecturer["image"] = $row["l_image"];
                $lecturer["degree"] = $row["degree"];
                $lecturer["name"] = $row["l_name"];
                $lecturer["surname"] = $row["surname"];
                $lecturer["field"] = array();
                $lecturer["field"]["fieldid"] = $row["fieldid"];
                $lecturer["field"]["name"] = $row["f_name"];

                array_push($response["lecturer"], $lecturer);
            }
        }
/... json_encode etc.
```

So, there can be a situation, where one lecturer has 2 different fields, and I'm getting something like this:

```
{
    "lecturer": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "http://...",
            "degree": "PhD",
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "field": {
                "fieldid": 13,
                "name": "field1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "http://...",
            "degree": "PhD",
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "field": {
                "fieldid": 14,
                "name": "field2"
            }
        },
```

Instead of that, I would like to get JSON:

```
{
    "lecturer": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "http://...",
            "degree": "PhD",
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "field": {
                "fieldid": 13,
                "name": "field1",
                "fieldid": 14,
                "name": "field2"
            }
        },
```

In the MySQL database there are two tables: lecturer, and field, but also lecturer_field table, where I have relation between lecturerid and fieldid.

Comment: its not possible, you can't have duplicate keys, you'll just need to have another dimension inside that level

Comment: field would need to be an array. ie `"field" : [ { "fieldid" : 13, "name" : "field1" }, { "fieldid" : 14, "name" : "field2" } ],

Comment: So, you mean to change lecturer_field table and define for example five columns: field1, field2 ... and thanks to it eliminate duplicate keys lecturerid inside that table, and then prepare new query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i was pointed out, it's impossible to declare similar named field in json object:

```
"field": {
    "fieldid": 13,
    "name": "field1",
    "fieldid": 14,
    "name": "field2"
}
```

Valid case is

```
"field": [{
    "fieldid": 13,
    "name": "field1",
},
{
    "fieldid": 14,
    "name": "field2"
}]
```

You can do that in this way:

```
if ($statement->execute())
{
     $indexedLecturers = array();

     while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
        $lid = $row["lecturerid"];

        if (isset($indexedLecturers[$lid])) {
            array_push($indexedLecturers[$lid]["field"], array(
                "fieldid" => $row["fieldid"],
                "name" => $row["f_name"],
            ));
        } else {
            $lecturer = array();
            $lecturer["id"] = $lid;
            $lecturer["image"] = $row["l_image"];
            $lecturer["degree"] = $row["degree"];
            $lecturer["name"] = $row["l_name"];
            $lecturer["surname"] = $row["surname"];
            $lecturer["field"] = array();

            array_push($lecturer["field"], array(
                "fieldid" => $row["fieldid"],
                "name" => $row["f_name"],
            ));

            $indexedLecturers[$lid] = $lecturer;
        }
    }

    $response['lecturer'] = array_values($indexedLecturers);
}
```